# crystal reports--Display 3 details section one after the other

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I am creating a new crystal report I want to design my report in such way that Report should print 3 Data tables(ADo.net) data.

each table should display its data one after the other.

Is there anyway to do this?

I tried creating 3 different details sections and each section will display one table data but every thing getting overlapped.

I tried one detail and one report footer its working but how to put the content of third table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend this approach:

Main report
 * no database

Subreport 0
 * connected to first dataset

Subreport 1
 * connected to second dataset

Subreport 2
 * connected to third dataset

If you need to correlate the subreport, create a parameter in the main report, then link each subreport to the main report on the parameter field.  Each subreport would use the parameter field to filter your dataset.

** edit **

If the datasets are already filtered by your logic, then there is no need to link the subreports.

While it may be a bit unconventional, this approach will keep your report tidy.

Comment: yes its working when you create your main report without any Dataset and Subreports with indvidual data set.        But I am confused " 

I recommend this approach:

Main report * no database

Subreport 0 * connected to first dataset

Subreport 1 * connected to second dataset

Subreport 2 * connected to third dataset

If you need to correlate the subreport, create a parameter in the main report, then link each subreport to the main report on the parameter field. Each subreport would use the parameter field to filter your dataset." could you pls eloborate

Comment: Srikanth, I think Craig's idea would be one of these two concepts: 1) You make the main report accept parameters such as 'OrderNumber'. Then subreport0-2 would all be linked to 'OrderNumber' from the main report. This way the subreport data is driven by the main report OR 2) You nest the reports so mainreport is linked to subreport0, then subreport1 is INSIDE and linked to subreport0, then subreport2 is INSIDE and linked to subreport1, etc.

Comment: Dylan, Crystal Reports won't allow subreports within other subreports.  Your first point is what I meant by 'correlated'.